# How to add a button to Form View's action without creating Wizard

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10

I want to add a button inside Action found in Form View.I don't want to create a seperate wizard for it.`crm.lead` is my model.

*Python Code*

```
def create_booking(self):
    print "hello_from_booking"
    print "hello_from_booking"
    print "hello_from_booking"
```

*XML*

```
<record id="create_booking_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">create_booking</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Create Booking">
       </form>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="action_view_create_booking" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Create Booking</field>
    <field name="res_model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="create_booking_form"/>
    <field name="target">new</field>
</record>

<record model="ir.values" id="action_create_booking">
    <field name="name">Create Booking</field>
    <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
    <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.act_window,' +str(ref('action_view_create_booking'))" />
    <field name="key">action</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
</record>
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: what is your issue?

Comment: I want to call a function when I click on a 'Custom Action' without using the Wizard.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an ir.actions.server instead of ir.actions.act_window to be able to run a custom action code directly from the action "Create Booking"